# How to place border around all @objects (not each object)?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I put a `challenges-border` around all the `Date.current` challenges?

The problem with this first example is that the border is placed around each challenge, but I want the border to be placed around all the challenges that are `Date.current`.

### Attempt #1

```
<% @challenges.each do |challenge| %>
  <% if challenge.deadline == Date.current %>
    <div class="challenges-border">
      <%= challenge.deadline %>: <%= challenge.action %>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <%= challenge.deadline %>: <%= challenge.action %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

### Attempt #2

I get error `deadline` undefined method

```
<% if @challenges.deadline == Date.current %>
  <div class="challenges-border">
<% end %>

<% @challenges.each do |challenge| %>
  <%= challenge.deadline %>: <%= challenge.action %>
<% end %>

<% if @challenges.deadline == Date.current %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### Attempt #3

This doesn't work because I want the challenges to be organized in descending order via deadline, which means `Date.current` challenges could appear in the middle of the list instead of listing them all as `@todays_challenges` at the end.

```
<% @challenges.each do |challenge| %>
  <%= challenge.deadline %>: <%= challenge.action %>
<% end %>

<div class="challenges-border">
  <% @todays_challenges.each do |challenge| %>
    <%= challenge.deadline %>: <%= challenge.action %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure you have a challenge that evaluates to false with this ```challenge.deadline == Date.current``` ? because there appears to be nothing wrong with your first example.

Comment: Yeah i get that, what i'm wondering is if you have any challenges that do not have Date.current. do something random in your ```else``` block like ```raise 'foobar'``` and make sure you are actually getting to the else block at some point in that loop

Comment: Yes. foobar is raised @MilesStanfield

Answer (score 0):

> I want the border to be placed around all the challenges that are Date.current

```
<div class="challenges-border">
  <% @challenges.current.each do |challenge| %>  
    <%= challenge.deadline %>: <%= challenge.action %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div>
  <% @challenges.not_current.each do |challenge| %>  
    <%= challenge.deadline %>: <%= challenge.action %>
  <% end %>
</div>

class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :current, -> { where(deadline: Date.current) }
  scope :not_current, -> { where.not(deadline: Date.current) }
end
```

Comment: Miles please see Attempt 3

Comment: I (and others) cannot understand what you want from your question. It is very unclear. consider revising again